# 'No data to import' when importing .stf with Translation Workbench

Tags: translation, language, translation-workbench

I'm having some trouble with importing .stf files in Translation Workbench: sometimes I get the following error in log file:

> There were issues with import of file: t.stf
>   [No data to import.]

But the file clearly contains data. Furthermore, I can swear that it successfully imported the exact file in the past, but now it doesn't want to no matter how many times I try. I tried changing line endings but to no avail. 
I found some solution in a Knowledge Article:

> If you receive a "No Data to import" error and there is clearly data lines in your file, save the file with a new name and re-import the file.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I've got it. From the help page explaining what 'No data to import' message means:

> The file you’re trying to import is empty **or
>   does not contain any translation changes**.

It turned out that the file was actually imported earlier, so there were no changes detected in this import and it displayed this message.